# Where can I make API call with hooks in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

Basically we do API calls in `componentDidMount()` life cycle method in React class components like below

```
     componentDidMount(){
          //Here we do API call and do setState accordingly
     }
```

But after hooks are introduced in React v16.7.0, its all like functional components mostly

My query is, where exactly do we need to make API call in functional component with hooks?

Do we have any method for it similar like `componentDidMount()`?

Answer (score 147, accepted):

### 2023 Update: Load data on the server or use React Query

The newly-written [official docs](https://react.dev) provides an [example of how to fetch data with `useEffect` without race condition issues](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect#fetching-data-with-effects).

If you're using a metaframework like Next.js or Remix, they allow for data fetching on the server and passing the data to the components as props, which can eliminate the need for fetching data on the client. This tends to be better for UX and performance due elimination of the traditional fetch-after-you-render model, or prefetching data needed for the next page in the case of transitions.

If you want a pure client-side solutions which work well with Suspense:

- [React Query](https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/react/overview) is the most popular declarative data fetching library for React that provides useful features like caching, refetching, prefetching, etc.
- [SWR](https://swr.vercel.app/) is a more lightweight option.

---

### 2021 Update: Suspense

As Dan Abramov said on [this GitHub Issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14326):

> Longer term we'll discourage this (useEffect) pattern because it encourages race conditions. Such as — anything could happen between your call starts and ends, and you could have gotten new props. Instead, we'll recommend Suspense for data fetching

---

Yes, there's a similar (but not the same!) substitute for `componentDidMount` with hooks, and it's the `useEffect` hook.

The other answers don't really answer your question about where you can make API calls. You can make API calls by using `useEffect` and **passing in an empty array or object as the second argument** as a replacement for `componentDidMount()`. The key here is the second argument. If you don't provide an empty array or object as the second argument, the API call will be called on every render, and it effectively becomes a `componentDidUpdate`.

As mentioned in the docs:

> Passing in an empty array [] of inputs tells React that your effect doesn’t depend on any values from the component, so that effect would run only on mount and clean up on unmount; it won’t run on updates.

Here are some examples for scenarios where you will need to make API calls:

### API Call Strictly on Mount

Try running the code below and see the result.

```js
function User() {
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = React.useState(null);
  const [lastName, setLastName] = React.useState(null);
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/')
      .then(results => results.json())
      .then(data => {
        const {name} = data.results[0];
        setFirstName(name.first);
        setLastName(name.last);
      });
  }, []); // <-- Have to pass in [] here!

  return (
    <div>
      Name: {!firstName || !lastName ? 'Loading...' : `${firstName} ${lastName}`}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<User />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

### API Call Whenever Some Prop/State Changes

If you are for example displaying a profile page of a user where each page has a userID state/prop, you should pass in that ID as a value into the second parameter of `useEffect` so that the data will be refetched for a new user ID. `componentDidMount` is insufficient here as the component might not need remounting if you go directly from user A to user B's profile.

In the traditional classes way, you would do:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.fetchData();
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (prevState.id !== this.state.id) {
    this.fetchData();
  }
}
```

With hooks, that would be:

```
useEffect(() => {
  this.fetchData();
}, [id]);
```

Try running the code below and see the result. Change the id to 2 for instance to see that `useEffect` is run again.

```js
function Todo() {
  const [todo, setTodo] = React.useState(null);
  const [id, setId] = React.useState(1);
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (id == null || id === '') {
      return;
    }
    
    fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${id}`)
      .then(results => results.json())
      .then(data => {
        setTodo(data);
      });
  }, [id]); // useEffect will trigger whenever id is different.

  return (
    <div>
      <input value={id} onChange={e => setId(e.target.value)}/>
      <br/>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(todo, null, 2)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Todo />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.8.1/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.8.1/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

You should read up on [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) so that you know what you can/cannot do with it.

Comment: This is an excellent explanation on how to use reacts useEffect hook. But i believe this particular hook has a bug on componentDidMount life cycle method implementation as it has repetitive calls unless the second argument is provided.

Comment: @HusniJabir you mean my example is incorrect? Didn't I pass in an empty array as the second argument?

Comment: I didn't mean that your example is incorrect, what I wanted to emphasize is if there is no second argument as empty array then the useEffect hook will run infinitely and that is a bug with the original hook implementation.

Comment: I see, feel free to edit the answer to warn about that part :)

Comment: This works but passing an empty array into useEffect it'll complain about any properties or methods you're using inside useEffect and aren't defined in the dependency array. "React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'getData'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps"

Comment: @Organic Then include the dependencies? The example code here doesn't use a custom function to call the API so there's no need for dependencies. Thanks for the downvote :)

Comment: If you include the dependencies in the array it doesn't just run once. It runs several times, sometimes on an infinite loop. Hooks cause more issues than they solve.

Comment: This has the distinct disadvantage of [invoking twice when using Strict Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72238175/1264804) in development. This results in duplicate ajax calls, key duplication errors, etc. This is hinted at in the final paragraph, but no real solution is provided here.

Comment: This *was* a fantastic answer, but the prophecy from Dan at the end has long come and gone. I'm still researching the best ways to do API calls in React now and finding it surprisingly hard, but what is clear is that everyone says we shouldn't be putting API calls in `useEffect()` now.

Comment: @AaronBeall Short answer: if you're using a metaframework like Next.js/Remix, load data on the server. If you're loading data on the client, use React Query. I'll update the answer with modern recommendations.

Comment: @YangshunTay Thanks, I'll check out those frameworks! Currently not using any of those.

Answer (score 13):

I am just posting this as a simpler way to understand acc. to my efforts. Credit to Yangshun Tay's post that it covers almost everything.

### API call on mounting of component

Code:

```
  useEffect(() => { 
    // here is where you make API call(s) or any side effects
    fetchData('/data')
  }, [] ) /** passing empty brackets is necessary */
```

So using `useEffect(fn,[])` with empty args as `[]` makes `fn()` triggered **once** throughout when component creates(mounts) and destroys(unmounts) without depending on any values.

**Pro tip:**

Also further if you `return()` something in this `fn` then it will act same as `componentWillUnmount()` lifecycle as that of class component.

```
  useEffect(() => { 
   fetchData('/data')
   return () => {
    // this will be performed when component will unmount
    resetData()
   }
  }, [] )
```

### API call when some value changes

If you are looking to call API when some value changes, simply pass that variable (which is storing value) into arguments array in `useEffect()`.

```
 useEffect(() => {
  // perform your API call here
  updateDetails();
 },[prop.name]) /** --> will be triggered whenever value of prop.name changes */
```

This will make sure that whenever value of `prop.name` changes, your function in hook gets triggered.

**Also to note**: this hook will be also called initially when the component is mounted. So at that time your name value might be in initial state which is kind of unintended from your view. So you can add custom condition in your function to avoid unnecessary API calls.

Comment: Voted this up because of the given important *note* at the end: "... So you can add custom condition in your function to avoid unnecessary API calls." 

Answer (score 10):

You can use a library that provides the hooks for you like https://dataclient.io

Then getting your data becomes as simple as:

```js
const todo = useSuspense(TodoResource.get, { id });
```

```js
function Todo({id}) {
  const todo = useSuspense(TodoResource.get, { id });

  return <pre>{JSON.stringify(todo, null, 2)}</pre>;
}

const TodoResource = Rest.createResource({
  urlPrefix: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com',
  path: '/todos/:id',
  schema: Rest.schema.Entity(class Todo {}),
});

var { CacheProvider, AsyncBoundary, useSuspense } = RDC;

function App() {
  const [id, setId] = React.useState(1);

  return (
   <div>
    <input value={id} onChange={e => setId(e.target.value)}/>
    <br/>
    <AsyncBoundary><Todo id={id} /></AsyncBoundary>
   </div>
  );
}
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector('#app')).render(<CacheProvider><App/></CacheProvider>);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@data-client/react@0.9.4/dist/index.umd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@data-client/rest@0.9.4/dist/index.umd.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Now you grabbed the article by id. All non-happy paths (loading, error states) are handled by [Suspense and Error boundaries](https://dataclient.io/docs/getting-started/data-dependency#async-fallbacks) respectively.

Any [mutations are atomic and immediate](https://dataclient.io/docs/getting-started/mutations)

To get started follow this simple guide: https://dataclient.io/docs/getting-started/installation

At only 9kb gzipped this will save you a lot of pain and in the long run lower your bundle size due to less repeated code.

[Demos](https://dataclient.io/demos)

Answer (score 3):

When you are using functional components with the hooks API, you can use the `useEffect()` method to produce side effects. Whenever the state is updated because of these side effects, the component will re-render.

## Example from the docs.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function Example() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  // Similar to componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate:
  useEffect(() => {
    // Update the document title using the browser API
    document.title = `You clicked ${count} times`;
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

For example, you could call `setCount` in a callback function of an async request. When the callback is executed, the state will get updated and React will re-render the component. Also from the docs:

> **Tip**
>
> If you’re familiar with React class lifecycle methods, you can think
>   of useEffect Hook as `componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate`, and
>   `componentWillUnmount` combined.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use [`use-http`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-http) like:

```
import useFetch from 'use-http'

function App() {
  // add whatever other options you would add to `fetch` such as headers
  const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    body: {}, // whatever data you want to send
  }

  var [data, loading, error] = useFetch('https://example.com', options)

  // want to use object destructuring? You can do that too
  var { data, loading, error } = useFetch('https://example.com', options)

  if (error) {
    return 'Error!'
  }

  if (loading) {
    return 'Loading!'
  }

  return (
    <code>
      <pre>{data}</pre>
    </code>
  )
}
```