# Why is the variable used before it is assigned?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to React Native and struggling with some code:

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler'
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, Image, TextInput, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native'
import firebase from "../utils/firebase"

const SettingsScreen = () => {

     const [isEditing, setIsEditing] = useState(false)
     const [userDataLoaded, setUserDataLoaded] = useState(false)

     const [updatedFirstName, setUpdatedFirstName] = useState("")


     const user = firebase.auth().currentUser
     let userData: firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot
     firebase.firestore().doc("users/" + user?.uid).get().then(user => {
          userData = user
          setUserDataLoaded(true)
     }).catch(error => {
          console.log(error.code, error.message)
     })

     function onSaveChanges() {

     }

     return (
          <View>
               {userDataLoaded ? (
                    <>
                         {/* Change Editing Permission */}
                         < Button title={isEditing ? "Save Changes" : "Edit"} onPress={() => {
                              setIsEditing(!isEditing)
                              // save changes
                              if (isEditing) onSaveChanges();
                         }} />
                         {/* First Name */}
                         <Text>User: {userData.data()}</Text>
                         <TextInput
                              editable={isEditing}
                              placeholder="First Name"
                              onChangeText={text => setUpdatedFirstName(text)}
                         // value={updatedFirstName == "" ? userData?.get("firstName") : updatedFirstName}
                         />
                    </>
               ) : (
                         <ActivityIndicator />
                    )}
          </View>
     )
}

export default SettingsScreen
```

I'm getting an error, because of the use of `userData` in the return section. It says that the variable is used before its assigned.

My understanding is that React is rendering the section, in which `userData` is being used in, only if the state `userDataLoaded` is set to `true`. And `userDataLoaded` only is set to `true` if `userData` is assigned by the data loaded from the server.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your support :)

Comment: `let userData: firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot` pretty it's just a typo. It should be an equal sign

Comment: Async. You're assigning `userData` inside the function passed to `then`. There's no way for the static analyzer to know that there's any relation between `userData` and `userDataLoaded`.

Comment: @Andrew That's how you tell TypeScript what type of data will be in `userData`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Oh, yea I know of the TS syntax. I wasn't sure whether or not he was using TS. Didn't see it in the tag, didn't specify where the error was, and didn't see any other type declarations lol

Comment: But to answer your question Isc, you can either pull up `userData` outside of the function to its outer scope, which I personally wouldn't do, or assign `userData` using `useState` instead of using a regular variable.

Comment: @Andrew yep, works perfectly fine for me. Thank u

Comment: And thanks to @HereticMonkey for your explanation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: And specifically, here's [an example with React hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53219113/1218980).

Comment: @EmileBergeron I am already familiar with async stuff, but new to React (Native) and somehow thought – hoped – my solution could work. But the post you linked about React Hooks helped me to get a deeper understanding of it, thank you ;)