# React Router v6 and ownParams doesnt work like v5

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-redux, react-router-dom

Hello in react router dom v5 i can get params inside redux. Sample code is below:

1- passing parameter

```
<Route path="/saveproduct/:productId" component={AddOrUpdateProduct} />
```

2- get params inside redux. I can get the productId inside ownProps

```
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {...
```

But when i call route in v6 i cant get the productId inside ownProps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im new at react and it take my one day. But finally i found the solution.  I am not sure this is the best practice but it make sense for me now. Check link for solution.

https://youtu.be/qdCHEUaFhBk
Also thanks @kupp

Answer (score 0):

First, in react-router-dom v6 you should pass component to Route like an element. See [docs](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview).

```
<Route path="/saveproduct/:productId" element={ <AddOrUpdateProduct /> } />
```

Second,

> react-router-dom v6 Route components rendered via the element prop don't receive route props

See [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64782949/how-to-pass-params-into-link-using-react-router-v6). Redux is not needed here. Just use params react hook

```
const { productId } = useParams();
```

Comment: But i need to get data from api before and then return them into page ?

Comment: If at the time of loading this component there is no necessary data in the Redux store, it must be requested from the API. Keep using Redux for storing API data, but do not store the URL params.

Comment: Ok but when i should call api? In use effect? In return i am passing the params to another component.

Comment: Ya, best practice is useEffect() without deps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53219113/where-can-i-make-api-call-with-hooks-in-react