# Issue in calling a 3rd party API via Axios in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, axios

**Problem Statement:-** i wanted to have a respective post-office dropdown for the user entered pincode. In this way, i have used below mentioned api to call with axios. I got the required post office details in the dropdown but the problem is that the fetching of data never stops, i keep getting the extracted data from API continuously and it never stops until I close the server. Below is my mentioned code.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import axios from "axios"

export default function Test() {
    const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState("");
    const [districtName, setDistrictName] = React.useState("");
    const [stateName, setStateName] = React.useState("");
    const [dataArray, setDataArray] = React.useState("")
    const onChangeHandler = event => {
        setInputValue(event.target.value);
    };

    if (inputValue.length === 6) {
        console.log(inputValue)
        axios.get("https://api.postalpincode.in/pincode/" + inputValue).then(res => {
            var data = res.data;
            console.log("data: ", JSON.stringify(data))
            setDistrictName(data[0].PostOffice[0].District)
            setStateName(data[0].PostOffice[0].State)
            console.log("data_1: ", districtName + " " + stateName)
            var items = []
            data[0].PostOffice.forEach(element => {
                items.push(<option value={element.Name}>{element.Name}</option>)
                
            });
            setDataArray(items);
            console.log("items:",items);
        })
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <label type="text" name="pincode">Pincode</label>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    name="pincode"
                    onChange={onChangeHandler}
                    value={inputValue}
                />
            </div>

            <div>

                <label type="text" name="district">District</label>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    name="district"
                    value={districtName}

                />
            </div>

            <div>
                <label type="text" name="state">State</label>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    name="state"
                    value={stateName}
                />
            </div>

            
                <select>
                    {dataArray}
                </select>

        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where can I make API call with hooks in react?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53219113/where-can-i-make-api-call-with-hooks-in-react)

Comment: No, your mentioned question is about how to call API. however, my problem is that API is getting called continuously and it never stops until i refresh the page.
Fetching of API should have been stopped after i received the data.

Comment: You have to call inside useEffect. Right now it is called every time it is rendered. Don't you wan to call it only once?

Comment: Render -> API Called -> State set -> Rendered -> API called -> State set -> Rendered . Like this. With useEffect you have control, specifically when you want to call code. Read about componendDidMount and componentDidUpdate too (from React class components)

Comment: Thank you for your help too, Will also try to do the same from useEffect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following change in your **onChangeHandler()** function. It should fix the issue.

The issue was when you were updating the state (`setInputValue`) in the `onChangeHandler()` function, the component gets rerender. But inside the if condition you were updating the state again (`setDistrictName`, `setStateName` and `setDataArray` ) which cause some sort of an infinite loop.If you put that if conditon inside the `onChangeHandler()` function, It will prevent your component from rerendering again and again.

```
    const onChangeHandler = event => {
        setInputValue(event.target.value);
        if (event.target.value.length === 6) {
          console.log(inputValue)
          axios.get("https://api.postalpincode.in/pincode/" + event.target.value).then(res => {
              var data = res.data;
              console.log("data: ", JSON.stringify(data))
              setDistrictName(data[0].PostOffice[0].District)
              setStateName(data[0].PostOffice[0].State)
              console.log("data_1: ", districtName + " " + stateName)
              var items = []
              data[0].PostOffice.forEach(element => {
                  items.push(<option value={element.Name}>{element.Name}</option>)
                  
              });
              setDataArray(items);
              console.log("items:",items);
          })
      }
    };
```

**Full react code :**

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import axios from "axios"

export default function Test() {
    const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState("");
    const [districtName, setDistrictName] = React.useState("");
    const [stateName, setStateName] = React.useState("");
    const [dataArray, setDataArray] = React.useState("")
    const onChangeHandler = event => {
        setInputValue(event.target.value);
        if (event.target.value.length === 6) {
          console.log(inputValue)
          axios.get("https://api.postalpincode.in/pincode/" + event.target.value).then(res => {
              var data = res.data;
              console.log("data: ", JSON.stringify(data))
              setDistrictName(data[0].PostOffice[0].District)
              setStateName(data[0].PostOffice[0].State)
              console.log("data_1: ", districtName + " " + stateName)
              var items = []
              data[0].PostOffice.forEach(element => {
                  items.push(<option value={element.Name}>{element.Name}</option>)
                  
              });
              setDataArray(items);
              console.log("items:",items);
          })
      }
    };



    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <label type="text" name="pincode">Pincode</label>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    name="pincode"
                    onChange={onChangeHandler}
                    value={inputValue}
                />
            </div>

            <div>

                <label type="text" name="district">District</label>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    name="district"
                    value={districtName}

                />
            </div>

            <div>
                <label type="text" name="state">State</label>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    name="state"
                    value={stateName}
                />
            </div>

            
                <select>
                    {dataArray}
                </select>

        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you have solved my problem. It is working fine now.